# Java place a "-" between odd numbers in a string using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to place a `-`between all odd numbers in a string. So if a string is passed in as `Hel776o` it should output `Hel7-76o`. Dashes should only be placed between two consecutive odd numbers.

I am trying to do this in one line via String.replaceAll()

I have the following line:

```
return str.replaceAll(".*([13579])([13579]).*","$1-$2");
```

If any odd number, followed by an odd number place a `-` between them. But it's destructively replacing everything except for the last match.

Eg if I pass in `"999477"` it will output `7-7` instead of`9-9-947-7`. Are more groupings needed so I don't replace everything except the matches?

I already did this with a traditional loop through each char in string but wanted to do it in a one-liner with regex replace.

Edit: I should say I meant `return str.replaceAll(".*([13579])([13579]).*","$0-$1");` and not `$1` and `$2`

Comment: Take out the `.*` as this will drop everything before the last two odd digits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove `.*` from your regex to prevent consuming all characters in one match.

Also if you want to reuse some part of previously match you can't consume it. For instance if your string will be `135` and you will match `13` you will not be able to reuse that matched `3` again in next match with `5`.
To solve this problem use [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms which are [zero-length](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html) which means they will not consume part they match.

So to describe place which has

- odd number before use look behind `(?<=[13579])`,
- odd number after it use look-ahead `(?=[13579])`.

So your code can look like

```
return str.replaceAll("(?<=[13579])(?=[13579])","-");
```

---

You can also let regex consume only one of two odd numbers to let other one be reused:

```
return str.replaceAll("[13579](?=[13579])","$0-");

return str.replaceAll("(?<=[13579])[13579]","-$0");
```

Comment: That explanation helps. I didn't realize that a look-around mechanism existed which won't consume the character I just processed. I also forgot to update my code to use $0 and $1 instead of $1 and $2 by mistake!

Comment: In your case using `$1` and `$2` seemed correct. I am using `$0` which represent entire match, because I didn't add any explicit capturing group.

Comment: I modified it as: return str.replaceAll("([13579])(?=[13579])","$1-"); I am trying to learn the nuances of regex and for now I am finding it easier to do an explicit group capture

Comment: Feel free do to so. You can also name this group if it makes it more readable for you :) `replaceAll("(?<firstOddNumber>[13579])(?=[13579])","${firstOddNumber}-")`

Comment: That is even more helpful. Thank you for all the helpful information :)